# Reduce memory usage of python database script

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, sqlalchemy

I've written a script to populate a database table from a list of objects.

I'd like to refactor the code so that it consumes less memory.

The code works like this:

1. Loops through the list and appends certain attributes to a `list`
2. Creates a `pandas DataFrame` from the list
3. Defines a table with `SQLAlchemy`
4. Loads the `DataFrame` into the table using `pandas` `to_sql` function

I was wondering, is there a more memory-light way of achieving this?

For example, would it be better to populate the database in the `for` loop?

I did try that initially, but ran into an error in which the connection to the database kept on closing before the loop had finished.

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

#issues_list is the list of objects
issues_list=[item for sublist in issues_set for item in sublist]

data=[]

for issue in issues_list:
    if getattr(issue,'Spent time',0) != 0 or "E-" in issue.id:
        for work_item in connection.getWorkItems(issue.id): #this is an API call
            data.append({'user':work_item.authorLogin,
                      'date':work_item.date,
                      'time':work_item.duration,
                      'id':work_item.id,
                      'ticket':issue.id,
                      'updated':issue.updated,
                      'timestamp':time.time()*1000.0})

df1=pd.DataFrame(data)

Base = declarative_base()

class Work(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Work'
    id = Column(String(250),primary_key=True)
    user = Column(String(250),primary_key=False)
    date = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)
    time = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)
    ticket = Column(String(250), primary_key=False)
    updated = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)
    timestamp = Column(Integer, primary_key=False)

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///sqlalchemy_example2.db', pool_recycle=3600)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

df1.to_sql('Work',engine,index=False,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: @idjaw - thanks idjaw, I did think it might be suitable for that site, but I can't provide data for people to test it - does that matter?

Comment: Sorry, =/ I never really posted anything on that site, that is why I provided the link.